# Self defined function works for a defined list but does not work when I apply to a column in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with a column `tokens` which is an object data type, that stores a list of tokenized phrases from an application. I am trying to create another column for each row with a boolean value, which will be True if the list in `tokens` contains at least one of the words from the following list called `synonyms`.

I have defined the function called `has_item(x)` which works on a list I defined, like `my_list`, but it doesn't work when I try to apply the function to the column that stores the tokenized responses, which would create the new column I need. This it what the code looks like.

```
my_list = ['completing', 'degree', 'health', 'science', 'began']
synonyms =  ['design','build', 'create', 'develop', 'invent']

def has_word(x):
  return any(item in x for item in synonyms)

df['has_design'] = df['tokens'].apply(lambda x: has_word(x))
```

For example, `my_list` and `df.tokens[0]` contain the same strings but returns two different values. The correct value happens when I apply the function to the list but not the value from the DataFrame.

```
has_word(my_list) -> False

has_word(df.tokens[0]) -> True
```

I am not sure if `any()` is the right function to be using because I understand it returns True if any value in the argument you pass through is true.

Is there something about the way the values are stored in the DataFrame that wouldn't allow the function to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Update: OP's problem was that values in `df.tokens` were of `str` type instead of `list`.

```
df['tokens'] = df['tokens'].apply(eval)
```

should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your suggestion and it seems that when I try this every value in the new column is false, where I know some of them have to be true. Is there a way to ensure that the function is being applied correctly to each element in the column tokens ?

Comment: My apologies. Convert the series to an array and it should work. I have updated the code

Comment: Unfortunately this resulted in the same thing as before. Each value in the new column 'has_design' is still False. I have tried to change the axis to apply column wise but I get an error from the lambda function.

Comment: Put it simply, what does the new column `df['has_design']` represent? Specifically what determines if a row is `True` or `False`?

Comment: The new column is going to be used to select all the rows of the DataFrame where the value in `df[token]` has at least one of the string in synonyms. I am trying to apply the function `has_words(x)` to every entry in the column `df[tokens]` and create a new column with the boolean value from that output. The column `df[tokens]` is not the list, which I should have clarified. The entries in the column `df[tokens]` are lists themselves and that is what I want to apply `has_words(x)` too to make the new column.

Comment: Ok I understand the confusion here. Did you print your `df`? Is the column `has_design` accurate?

Comment: No it isn't accurate. There are particular entries in the new column where one of the words is not present in the entry in `df[tokens]` but it returns True.

Comment: Ah, I completely misread. My bad. `df[tokens]` is a column of lists. If that is the case, your code should work. Could you  specify what `df[tokens][0]` is? I can help debug

Comment: I have updated my answer. The results are consistent. Perhaps you can make a comparison.

Comment: df.tokens[0] is a list of strings that is the exact same as `my_list` above. That is why I am confused as to why the function doesn't work using `apply()` but it does if I test it using `has_word(my_list)` in a separate line. Maybe I am unclear as to what data type the column `tokens` is but when I check using df.dtypes it says it is an object.

Comment: It is highly possible df.tokens[0] is a `str` and not  a `list`, especially if you imported it from a csv. Check the type with `type(df.tokens[0])`

Comment: That was it. I checked the tokenizing function we used to create the column `tokens` from another column that was imported from a CSV and it was returning a `str` not as a `list`. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of help. To add on you can use `eval()` to rectify this problem easily. Have updated code.